# GridView takes the height of 1st element/gridItem rather than the height of tallest element/gridItem

Tags: android, gridview, height

I have a fixed number of elements, 3 to be precise, aligned horizontally in a SINGLE row, in my GridView.

Each Grid Element is a Linear layout with vertical orientation.
    
         //Fixed Size NOT OPTIONAL
         //Optional text
         //optional text
         //optional text
         //NOT OPTIONAL

As text1/text2/text3 are not compulsory, each GridElement has variable height. If the height of first GRIDELEMENT is less than the other two GRIDELEMENTS, the heights of GridElements two and three are cut as the GridView takes the height of the first element.

I want the GridView to take the height of the tallest element.

Please help me in resolving this issue.